# Setting iChat status from a web app

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, instant-messaging, ichat

I'd like my web app to be able to set ichat status: Available or Away + Custom message

Basically my web app is related to tracking and status so at present, you have to remember to update both (if you use iChat), which is a pain.

Is there a way to do this? using Javascript or the like?

Alternatively, the other way around would work too but I guess that would involve creating some sort of extension or plugin for iChat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in you link weather it be `javascript:window.location = ''` or `href=""` use this link `aim:goaway?message=hi` you can also do a javascript like `javascript:window.location = 'aim:goaway?message=' + new Date()` with a variable

Comment: Thanks man, So that should work with anything using the aim protocol. Do you know where there is a good reference to the available commands (i.e. 'goaway') cheers.

Comment: the available code does not work on macs, sorry, i looked long and hard